# Functionality testing with Test database/data for PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am kind of new to PHPUnit test so appreciate your help to see whether I'm following the right approach or not.

I'm trying to test my methods; I have two questions

1) How can I have my test database with dummy data? right now I have all of my database settings in pdo_connect class and in constructor of that class I'm doing all of the database initializations, including dbname, host,...; I have included my method that I want to test here and my test case as well; my question is whether it is a good practice to change my database for test based on different environments; for example if the 'environment' variable in my settings is 'test' I use the 'test' database which has dummy data and ...

2) Also I really appreciate it if you confirm my example test case which is mentioned below is the right way of functionality testing of my method!

```
static public function get_images($id) {
    try {
        $conn = new pdo_connect();
        $query = "  SELECT ....";
        $result = $conn->prepare($query);
        $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $result->execute();
        $array_result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);        
        $result_Set = array($paginate_result, TRUE);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $result_Set = array($e->getMessage(), FALSE);
    }
    return $result_Set;
}
```

and my test:

```
class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function __construct() {
        require_once('../includes/model.php');
    }
    public function test_id_not_exist() {
        $con = $this->getMock('conn');  
        $dao = new Model($con);
        $result = MODEL::get_images(555);
        $expected = array(array(), True);
        self::assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification... and again I appreciate it in advance...

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule: Testing static function can get tricky, but in your case it might work.

If this is your actual code, you can't switch to a test database, because you connect in get_images with $conn = new pdo_connect().

What you need is some way of dependency injection to insert the connection. You don't need to mock it, you can just use a real connection to the test database.

You could do that like that:

```
class Model {
    private static $_conn;

    public static function setDb($conn) {
        self::$_conn = $conn;
    }


    static public function get_images($id) {
        try {
            $conn   = self::$_conn;
            ...
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result_Set = array($e->getMessage(), false);
        }

        return $result_Set;
    }
}
```

Your test would become this (I also removed some other issues):

```
public function test_id_not_exist() {
    $con = new pdo_connect();
    Model::setDb($con);
    $result = Model::get_images(555);
    $expected = array(array(), True);
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

To seed your test database properly you would implement a setUp function in your test class, which then can insert some dummy data.